# regular expression match all except certain condition

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I capture lines that includes zip codes format from email. 
And trying to exclude certain zip code "12345"

How can I add this condition? .*(\d{5}).* *except 12345*

Comment: Use `^(?!.*12345).*\d{5}.*`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiizew I removed ^ and it works as what wanted. Many thanks!